# Why is my Instagram Feed in HTML and Shopify Liquid not showing up?

Tags: html, shopify, instagram, liquid

(sorry for my english) Hi i'm a beginner programmer and im'trying to embed my Instagram Feed on my website. This is the code i used to make it work, but for some reasons nothing appears on my page. This is shopify liquid:

```
{% schema %}

{

"name": "Instagram Posts",

"settings": [],

"presets": [

{

"name": "Instagram Posts", "category": "Custom"

}

]

}

{% endschema %}

{% assign instagramAccessToken = MYACCESSTOKEN %}

{% assign instagramEndpoint = "https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_url,permalink&access_token=" | append: instagramAccessToken %}

{% assign response = instagramEndpoint | json_api %}{% assign postsLimit = 4 %}

{% assign posts = response.data | slice: 0, postsLimit %}


{% for post in posts %}

{% assign mediaUrl = post.media_url %}

{% assign postLink = post.permalink %}

<a href="{{ postLink }}" target="\\\_blank"><img src="{{ mediaUrl }}" alt="Instagram Post" class="imgpost"></a>

{{ mediaUrl }}

{% endfor %}
```

I checked many times if my Instagram Token (I removed it on this version of the code) was correct and it actually is. I think there might be a problem with the updated version of Instagram API but i searched everywhere and didn't find any solution. I would really appreciate if you can help me.